# SSL/TLS issue with Paypal

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate, paypal

We are using ASP.net 3.5 and have integrated Paypal Pro in one of our customer's website. the staging environment & credentials work fine, however when we move it to Live environment we start getting "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'api-aa.paypal.com'." exception.

- we have got our certificate installed on the server with its
  respective private key.
- "Everyone" has been granted permissions to private key

We have been struggling with this weird issue for quite some time but not really been successful. any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out we just had to switch to a different Paypal URL and it worked. This is the URL we used and it worked like a charm - https://api-aa-3t.paypal.com/2.0/